# SQL - Filter common records from a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a table storing data about employees & their respective departments.

One employee can belong to > 1 department.

Without going much into details below is the result of one of my query from joins on multiple tables.

**Query:**

```
Select 
    e.EmpID,
    d.Department,
    ed.Date,
    ed.Action

from Employee e
    inner join Emp_Dept ed on ....
    inner join Department d on ....

where .....
```

**Data fetched:**

| EmpID | Department | Date | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Food | 01-01-2021 | ADDED |
| 2 | Food | 01-01-2021 | ADDED |
| 2 | Food | 04-01-2021 | REMOVED |
| 2 | Auto | 01-01-2021 | ADDED |
| 3 | Electric | 02-01-2021 | ADDED |
| 3 | Electric | 04-01-2021 | REMOVED |
| 3 | Auto | 04-01-2021 | REMOVED |

From this data I want to remove those emplyees who have been added & also removed in that department.

That is from above data EmpId 2 -> Food & EmpId 3 -> Electric should be excluded.

Please suggest how to filter this out?

Comment: Can a single employee be added to the same department twice? Should employee present in the dataset if he/she was added -> removed -> added?

Comment: @astentx, A very valid point. However my question is an oversimplification of a problem & your point has already been handled on my side. So you can ignore if a person is added->removed->added.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.action = 'ADDED' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.empid = t.empid and
                        t2.department = t.department and
                        t2.action = 'REMOVED'
                 );
```

EDIT:

If you want employees that have more added then removed for a given department:

```
select empid, deptid
from t
group by empid deptid
having sum(case when action = 'ADDED' then 1
                when action = 'REMOVED' then -1
           end);
```

Comment: Thank you. But I think this will only cover for the ADDED case & I'll have to do it for REMOVED as well.

I was thinking if I can filter out - if number of rows for same empid and department is more than 1 then remove those records.

Answer (score 1):

Use analytic [LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466) function to get the complet ehistory of the *action*s per employee and department

```
listagg(ACTION,',') within group (order by DATE_D, ACTION) over (partition by EMPID, DEPARTMENT) ACTION_LST
```

Note order is defined on DATE *and* `ACTION`, as if you are removed on the same day you probably want to see ADDED,REMOVED

Basic query (using your rowset as `tab`)

```
with dt as (
select EMPID, DEPARTMENT, DATE_D, ACTION,
listagg(ACTION,',') within group (order by DATE_D, ACTION) over (partition by EMPID, DEPARTMENT) ACTION_LST
from tab

EMPID, DEPARTMENT, DATE_D,          ACTION, ACTION_LST
1   Food        01.01.2021 00:00:00 ADDED   ADDED
2   Auto        01.01.2021 00:00:00 ADDED   ADDED
2   Food        01.01.2021 00:00:00 ADDED   ADDED,REMOVED
2   Food        04.01.2021 00:00:00 REMOVED ADDED,REMOVED
3   Auto        04.01.2021 00:00:00 REMOVED REMOVED
3   Electric    02.01.2021 00:00:00 ADDED   ADDED,REMOVED
3   Electric    04.01.2021 00:00:00 REMOVED ADDED,REMOVED
```

This approach is anyway interessting to see all distinct *combination of the actions*.

Now you simple add a filtering query that eliminates the not needed combinations:

```
with dt as (
select EMPID, DEPARTMENT, DATE_D, ACTION,
listagg(ACTION,',') within group (order by DATE_D, ACTION) over (partition by EMPID, DEPARTMENT) ACTION_LST
from tab)
select EMPID, DEPARTMENT, DATE_D, ACTION
from dt
where ACTION_LST not in ('ADDED,REMOVED')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select e.EmpID, d.Department
from Employee e
inner join Emp_Dept ed on ....
inner join Department d on ....
where .....
group by e.EmpID, d.Department
having count(distinct case when ed.Action in ('ADDED', 'REMOVED') THEN ed.Action END) < 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [pattern recognition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) feature of 12C and above (with more details in the [Data Warehousing Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/dwhsg/sql-pattern-matching-data-warehouses.html#GUID-136DAC89-DA17-45C6-9E37-C9892723AC79)), which can also handle sequences of additions and removals and looks quite natural here:

> ```
> select *
> from t
> match_recognize(
>   partition by empid, department
>   order by dt
>   /*Find matched rows*/
>   measures
>     classifier() as cls
>   /*To include all the rows and then filter out classified rows*/
>   all rows per match with unmatched rows
>   /*Addition followed by removal*/
>   pattern (add0 rem0)
>   define
>     add0 as action = 'ADDED',
>     rem0 as action = 'REMOVED'
> )
> /*Exclude matched (added -> removed)*/
> where cls is null
> ```
>
> ```
> EMPID | DEPARTMENT | DT        | CLS  | ACTION 
> ----: | :--------- | :-------- | :--- | :------
>     1 | Food       | 01-JAN-21 | null | ADDED  
>     2 | Auto       | 01-JAN-21 | null | ADDED  
>     3 | Auto       | 01-APR-21 | null | REMOVED
> ```

> ```
> /*Create a sequence of add -> remove -> add*/
> insert into t
> select 2, 'Food', date '2021-05-01', 'ADDED' from dual union all
> select 2, 'Food', date '2021-06-01', 'REMOVED' from dual union all
> select 2, 'Food', date '2021-07-01', 'ADDED' from dual
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from t
> match_recognize(
>   partition by empid, department
>   order by dt
>   measures
>     classifier() as cls
>   all rows per match with unmatched rows
>   pattern (add0 rem0)
>   define
>     add0 as action = 'ADDED',
>     rem0 as action = 'REMOVED'
> )
> where cls is null
> ```
>
> ```
> EMPID | DEPARTMENT | DT        | CLS  | ACTION 
> ----: | :--------- | :-------- | :--- | :------
>     1 | Food       | 01-JAN-21 | null | ADDED  
>     2 | Auto       | 01-JAN-21 | null | ADDED  
>     2 | Food       | 01-JUL-21 | null | ADDED  
>     3 | Auto       | 01-APR-21 | null | REMOVED
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=20b6407819e2231f7ef0437b3b9b5c24)*